# awk: Output to different processes

Tags: bash, awk

I have awk script which splits big file into several files by some condition. Than I'm running another script over each file in parallel.

```
awk -f script.awk -v DEST_FOLDER=tmp input.file
find tmp/ -name "*.part" | xargs -P $ALLOWED_CPUS --replace --verbose /bin/bash -c "./process.sh {}"
```

The question is: are there any way to run ./process.sh:

- before first script is done, because process.sh processes file line by line (one line too long to be passed to xargs directly);
- each new file has a header (added in script.awk) that should be run before the rest of file;
- limit amount of parallel processes;
- GNU parallel,inotifywait is not an option;
- assume dest folder is empty, files name are unknown.

The purpose of optimization to get rid of waiting until the awk is done while some files are ready to be processed.

Comment: what failure could be tolerated? E.g. your awk writes 100 lines in 1 minute to file f1, but your script.sh just took 10s to read 10 lines from f1, and done the work. is it ok?

Comment: Create named pipes for each of the output "files". Background a process.sh for each of them. You won't limit the number of processes that way, but as the speed of your awk script is the limiting factor, all but one or two of your processes will be blocked, waiting for more awk output. Also, when your awk script is finished with one file, and closes it, the corresponding reader process will get EOF and should exit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have created a file, you can pass the filename to a process' or script's input:

```
awk '{print name_of_created_file | "./process.sh &"}'
```

`&` sends `process.sh` to the background, so that they can run in parallel. However, this is a `gawk` extension and not POSIX. Check the [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Redirection.html)

Comment: How does this fulfill the requirement of 'limit amount of parallel processes;' ?

Comment: Currently not, you are right. First thing that comes in mind is some pidfile logic, but it's tricky

Answer (score 1):

You basically give the answer yourself: GNU Parallel + inotifywait will work.

Since you are not allowed to use inotifywait, you can make your substitute for inotifywait. If you are allowed to write your own script, you are also allowed to run GNU Parallel (as that is just a script).

So something like this:

```
awk -f script.awk -v DEST_FOLDER=tmp input.file &
sleep 1
record file sizes of files in tmp
while tmp is not empty do
  for files in tmp:
    if file size is unchanged: print file
    record new file size
  sleep 1
done | parallel 'process {}; rm {}'
```

It is assumed that `awk` will produce some output with one second. If that takes longer, adjust the sleeps accordingly.